# how to echo sum value in row

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i want to echo sum of 1st script in to 2nd script

and both are same page  i was try but not working 
example

```
echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$final_result4. '</td>';
```

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue thanks....

this is my 1st script

```
     $res1 = (($basicsalary+$allowsalary)*$days*$yeardays1)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res2 = (($basicsalary1+$allowsalary1)*$days*$yeardays2)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res3 = (($basicsalary2+$allowsalary2)*$days*$yeardays3)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res4 = (($basicsalary+$allowsalary)*$days*$yeardays4)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res5 = (($basicsalary1+$allowsalary1)*$days*$yeardays5)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res6 = (($basicsalary2+$allowsalary2)*$days*$yeardays6)/$yeardays/$monthdays;
     $res8 = 221/730*$miscamount +$otheramount;
     $res7 = $startdays -$enddays;

 $result1  = number_format((round($res1, 1)),3);
 $result2  = number_format((round($res2, 1)),3);
 $result3  = number_format((round($res3, 1)),3);
 $result4  = number_format((round($res4, 1)),3);
 $result5  = number_format((round($res5, 1)),3);
 $result6  = number_format((round($res6, 1)),3);
 $result7 = number_format((round($res7, 1)),3);
 $result8 = number_format((round($res8, 1)),3);




 $final_result   = number_format(($result1 +$result2 +$result3 +$result4 +$result5 +$result6 ),3);
     $final_result2   = number_format((round($final_result/730*$result7 ,1 )),3);
      $final_result3   = number_format((round(($final_result2 +$result8) , 1)),3);
       echo $final_result4   = number_format((round(($final_result -$final_result3) , 1)),3);


    //Ending of php
    ?>
```

this is my 2nd script

```
 echo "<span  align='center' class='style2'>Over All Report For The Period Of $a to $b</span>"; 
           echo "<div id='testTable' id='non-printable'><table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
            echo "<tr> <th>Date</th><th>Id</th><th>Name</th> <th>Division</th><th>Payment</th><th>Status</th><th>Total</th></tr>";


     // get results1 from database
          $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fullfsaccounts where date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by date ASC");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                    {   



                    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['cardno'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['division'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['typecash'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'  '</td>';         
                    echo "</tr>"; 

                //Increment the value of the Total_total variable
                //by the salary value of one row till the while loop finishes
                $Total_rows=$num=mysql_num_rows($result1);
                $Total_total=$Total_total+$row['total'];

        }
        echo "</table>";

        echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' >";
        echo "<tr width='100%'>";
       echo '<td>Total</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $Total_rows .'</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $Total_total .'</td>';
       echo "</tr>";  



            // close table>
            echo "</table>";
```

Comment: read about require in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have one basic error in line  echo ''  ''; your need
put  echo '' . '';

I think you also do not explain well because if they are on the same page as you say you should not have any problems to call the value of the local variables of the page.

I advise you to put different -> echo 'pass';  or echo 'pass : '.resultxxx:  in controls the flow of the page, I understand that if they are on the same page and do not get out and walk in it you should be able to pick up the value of the local variables without any problem.

Please explain more your problem if you need help.